# ruby / rails - hash max by :key does not return largest value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a query that looks for all events on a given date @s_date. Event start_datetime is within day OR - event end_datetime is within day

```
@s_hash_items = @company.events.where('(start_datetime > ? AND start_datetime < ?) OR 
  (end_datetime > ? AND end_datetime < ?)', 
          @s_date.beginning_of_day, @s_date.end_of_day, 
          @s_date.beginning_of_day, @s_date.end_of_day)
```

I am then trying to find the latest end_datetime value from this array. E.g. there are 3 events finishing at 14:00, 17:30 and 15:00, I want to return 17:30. But, if there is an event that runs over to the next day, I want the max result to be 23:59:59 on @s_date).

My code to do that looks like this

```
   @s_end_hour = [@s_hash_items2.max_by{:end_datetime}.end_datetime, Time.now.end_of_day].sort.first.hour
```

So it produces an array with latest end date time, and end of day, and picks out whichever one is earlier (sort.first), then returns the hour number, e.g. 17 in this case.

However, the max_by method is not finding the event with the latest end_datetime. It seems to vary depending on the order of the @s_hash_items result. But the order of @s_hash_items shouldn't matter - I just want the max value. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
@s_hash_items2.max_by{:end_datetime}
```

That's same as saying:

```
@s_hash_items2.max_by { 11 }
```

i.e. you're asking `max_by` to find the element with maximum `:end_datetime` Symbol (a constant value) and that's a bit pointless.

If you want [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to call the `end_datetime` method then you want a block that returns the the `end_datetime` value of the objects:

```
@s_hash_items2.max_by { |item| item.end_datetime }
```

or more concisely (and probably what you were trying to say):

```
@s_hash_items2.max_by(&:end_datetime)
```

The `&` more or less turns the symbol into the `{ |item| item.end_datetime }` block in the first previous example.

Comment: Yes from the Ruby enumerable doc: "Returns the object in enum that gives the maximum value from the given block. If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead."

Comment: Thanks, yes it was missing the &.